# C# - Explicit Interfaces with inheritance?

Tags: c#, inheritance, explicit-interface

*Output:*
B->Hello! from Explicit.

*Shouldn't it be:?*
A->Hello! from Explicit.

### Why doesn't explicit cast (IHello)a call IHello.Hello() from class A?

```
interface IHello
{
    void Hello();
}

class A : IHello
{

    public virtual void Hello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A->Hello!");
    }

    void IHello.Hello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A->Hello! from Explicit.");
    }
}

class B : A, IHello
{
    public override void Hello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B->Hello!");
    }

    void IHello.Hello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B->Hello! from Explicit.");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new B();
        ((IHello)a).Hello();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, it shouldn't.

The call to `Hello` is equivalent to the commented-out one - the route to getting an `IHello` doesn't matter (unless it requires execution-time checking or conversion); the compile-time type is just `IHello` either way, and the interface mapping is the same however you get there.

When an interface is explicitly implemented more than once in the type hierarchy, the implementation in the most-derived type is used. (When called via the interface.)

From section 13.4.4 of the C# 3.0 Specification:

> Interface mapping for a class or
>   struct C locates an implementation for
>   each member of each interface
>   specified in the base class list of C.
>   The implementation of a particular
>   interface member I.M, where I is the
>   interface in which the member M is
>   declared, is determined by examining
>   each class or struct S, starting with
>   C and repeating for each successive
>   base class of C, until a match is
>   located:
>
> - If S contains a declaration
>     of an explicit interface member
>     implementation that matches I and M,
>     then this member is the implementation
>     of I.M.
> - Otherwise, if S contains a declaration of a non-static public member that matches M, then this member is the implementation of I.M. If more than one member matches, it is unspecified which member is the implementation of I.M. This situation can only occur if S is a constructed type where the two members as declared in the generic type have different signatures, but the type arguments make their signatures identical.

Comment: +1. From a lower level perspective, there's a single method slot for `IHello.Hello` in the vtable for class B, where the implementation is going to be looked up.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! 
I though according to OOP rules having a reference of a base class point to an object of a derived class shadows out the fields and methods of the derived class not present in the base class. Is this then an exception to this rule?

Comment: @Naximus The type-system always knows exactly what the type of the object is. Assigning a `B` instance to an `A` field only says _"let_ my code _access the instance referenced by this field as if it was of type `A`"_. Later casting the field to `IHello` says _"temporarily let_ my code _access the instance referenced by this field as if it was of type `IHello`"_. The instance referenced still is and will always be of type `B`. This alone determines the outcome. Only time such actions does anything other than "change perspective" of an instance is when there are cast operators defined for it.

Comment: (cont...) To make a very abstract semi-correct visual geometric metaphor: Think of the object as being multi-dimensional, and your code looks at the object with a viewer capable of viewing the object through all it's different dimensions. The object my look very different depending on what dimension your code looks at it from (e.g. [tesseract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract)), but it's still the same object, and the assignment and cast operators simply changes in which dimensions the viewer views the object. ...but maybe this explanation is **too** abstract to be useful? I don't know.

Answer (score 3):

(A)a does nothing. The reference is already declared as a so casting it to A will have no effect.

Even though your reference is declared as A, the object which it refers to is of type B. If you cast this object to IHello, a call to Hello() will call object B's explicit implementation of Hello.

The output is exactly as expected.

Comment: (Note to readers: the question was edited after this answer was written. The first version of the question added `new string ToString()` in the mix, increasing confusion. For details see [Revisions to C# - Explicit Interfaces with inheritance? - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1856516/revisions).)

Answer (score 0):

No, when you create a **new** method (ToString), it is not virtual. New just means that you don't mind it "hiding" the version in the base class - so if you call it with a reference that you have cast to a specific type (A), it executes the method in class A, regardless of the actual type of the object you are calling. (i.e you called A.ToString() so it executed A.ToString())

When you create a **virtual** method, then regardless of what type you cast the reference to, the implementation from the actual type of the object is used (i.e you created a B, so when you called (whatever the object is).Hello, it called B.Hello)

The crucial difference is that one call is virtual and the other is not.

Comment: (Note to readers: the question was edited after this answer was written. The first version of the question added `new string ToString()` in the mix, increasing confusion. For details see [Revisions to C# - Explicit Interfaces with inheritance? - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1856516/revisions).)

Answer (score 0):

No, it shouldn't.

When you are calling a virtual method, it doesn't matter what the type of the reference is. The method that is called is determined by the actual type of the object, not the type of the reference.

As you create an instance of the class `B`, the actual type of the object is `B`. The reason that it prints `"This is class A."` is that you have not overridden the `ToString` method in the class `B`, you have shadowed it using the `new` keyword. Therefore the `B` class has two `ToString` methods, one inherited from the class `A` and one that shadows it. If you use an `A` reference to call the `ToString` method, the inherited method is called, but if you would have used a `B` reference to call it, the shadowing method would be called, printing out `"This is class B."`.

Also if you override the `ToString` method in the class `B` instead of shadowing it, it would print out `"This is class B."` regardless of the type of the reference.

Comment: (Note to readers: the question was edited after this answer was written. The first version of the question added `new string ToString()` in the mix, increasing confusion. For details see [Revisions to C# - Explicit Interfaces with inheritance? - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1856516/revisions).)